# C# Assign MySql Connection per thread

Tags: c#, mysql

I guess this is a simple question, how do I create a new connection per thread?

Umm basically i'm using a windows service to call in 3 instances of the same process, however each of them must have their own connection.  I'm using this right now to grab my connection.

```
public static MySqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public static MySqlConnection OpenCon()
    {
        MySqlConnection masterOpenCON = new MySqlConnection(StaticStringClass.masterConString);
        masterOpenCON.Open();
        return masterOpenCON;
    }
```

trying to resolve this error:  There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection

Answer (score 2):

Despite my initial urges, I'm not going to critique your design. I'm only answering your question given the code snippet you've presented:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static MySqlConnection _connection;

public static MySqlConnection GetConnection() {
    // no need for locks on a threadstatic field, obviously.
    if (_connection == null) {
        _connection = new MySqlConnection(...);
        _connection.Open();
    }
    return _connection;
}
```

Hope this helps. Read up on ThreadStaticAttribute for more information. Oh, and remember that it's each thread's responsibility to close their own connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you call OpenCon() from each thread it works...

otherwise if you use Connection property then you need to put the code `{ return Open(); }` into the get handler....

Comment: -1: it doesn't work if one thread decides to open a datareader, which is entirely his problem. Also, your answer makes zero sense.

Comment: it does work because he is calling "new" and returning a fresh connection on every call !

Comment: your answer is still technically nicer +1 :-)

Comment: @yahia thanks - the main advantage is that mine guarantees one per thread for one or more calls.